# PHP Inserting variables in array, but can't json_encode

Tags: php, arrays, json

Im with this for days, i tested if variables are being filled and they are, but i think somehow im not doing array right because 'echo json_encode($response)' is printing nothing. I also tried to replace variables in array to just random numbers and everything went fine, just with variables does work.

```
public function getPlaces() {
    $places = array();
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM poi ";
    $retval = mysqli_query( $this->conn, $stmt ); 

    if ($retval) {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($retval)) { 
            $name = $row["name"]; 
            $lat = $row["latitude"];
            $lng = row["longitude"];
            $desc = $row["descricao"];
            $rating = $row["rating"];
            $lm = $row["lm"];
            $la = $row["la"];
            $lv = $row["lv"];

            $places[] = array('name'=> $name, 'lat'=> $lat, 'lng'=> $lng, 'desc'=> $desc, 'rating'=> $rating,
                'lm'=> $lm, 'la'=> $la, 'lv'=> $lv);
        }

        return $places;            

    }else
        return false;        
}
```

The function is called here:

```
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

$response = array("error" => FALSE);

$places = $db->getPlaces();

if ($places != false) {
    $response["places"] = $places;

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Error";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Show the value of $response (with `var_dump($response);die;`) just before the json_encode.

Comment: `echo json_encode($response)` is not a good way to diagnose JSON problems. Please try `var_dump(json_encode($response), json_last_error_msg());` and update the question with the output.

Comment: Your answer helped me @ÁlvaroGonzález ty! The error was  "Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded" I will update with the solution i found.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using associative array, use `mysqli_fetch_object(`) to get the result set as object. You do not have to type all the field names if you use [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php).

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($retval)):
      array_push($places, $row);          
endwhile;
```

Vardump the `$places` array to check the array.

E.g.

```
vardump($places); die;
```

or

```
print_r($places); die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice the $ is missing before the $row variable on that line ?

> $lng = row["longitude"];

This kind of missed (bad handled) Notice + Warning won't make your array.
Notice also that if your array is filled with some type of value it won't json_encode. Especially NaN values (thinking of this because of the nature of some fields like "rating" that could result in a NaN value).

Try by steps :
Dump your result for one line only with a LIMIT 1 in your SQL query to see if it works. Try only with one field...

Notice that `$places = [];`

is more optimized than a 
`$places = array();`

Same with
`$places[] = ['name'=> $name, ... ];`